# How to Launching context menu from Nautilus (open terminal has moved?)

Tags: gnome-terminal, context-menu, nautilus-actions

Prior to Ubuntu 22.10 you could open the context menu for the current directory by "right-clicking" on the directory in the toolbar.  That no longer works.

Now you must "left-click" on the 3 vertical dots in the path section to get the pull-down menu previously available by right-click

Answer (score 0):

Now you must "left-click" on the 3 vertical dots in the path section to get the pull-down menu previously available by right-click